# Can I set dynamic text to ErrorMessage in Required attribute?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, attributes, properties

is it possible to make Required error message *attribute* available in different languages according to a resource file or configuration?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
public string SenderName { get; set; }
```

We would like to make `"Please enter your name"` a dynamic text, read from resources of config file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute parameters need to be resolved in compile time, so this is not possible.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177221.aspx):

> Values passed to attributes must be known to the compiler at compile time.

You best option is to use satellite assemblies in the normal [.NET internationalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164008.aspx) scheme.